# Hide textarea if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox

So I have to figure out how to hide my text box when check box is not checked. We call the function that shows the check boxes and text boxes. So cant use  stuff. So any suggestions on how could the text box be hidden would be very helpful. And this is the code:

```
//this is the check box
var nodeTr = document.createElement("tr");
var td_tekst = document.createElement("td");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var echeckbox = document.createElement("input");
echeckbox.type="checkbox";
echeckbox.name = "//funktsioonide hindamine/funktsioon[" + count + "]/nagemine/vahend_0106";
td.appendChild(echeckbox);
td.innerHTML+="Prillid või kontaktläätsed ";

//and this is the text box
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
input.value = getAbivahendTekst(rowData.vahendid,"01.06");
input.className = "txt_left";
input.name = "//funktsioonide hindamine/funktsioon[" + count + "]/nagemine/vahend_0106/tekst";
input.style.width = "100px";
input.style.fontSize = "9pt";
var nodePrillid = input;
addChangeListener(input);
td.appendChild(input);nodeTr.appendChild(td_tekst);
nodeTr.appendChild(td);
evaluationContainer.appendChild(nodeTr);
```

Comment: prepare fiddle please

Comment: What do you mean by "So can't use stuff"?. Also, I [googled your exact question](https://www.google.com.au/#q=Hide+textarea+if+checkbox+is+unchecked) and heaps of results were returned, did you try any of them at all? Remember, we are here to help you solve problems with your code, not to write all your code for you. We aren't not-for-profit rent-a-coders. If you're looking for someone to just do all your work for you, hire a freelance dev from elance/freelancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use very simple `if` statement for cheking checkbox state. Then you can set `visibility` css rule to your input to hide the element.

```
var cb = document.getElementById('CHECKBOX_ID'); // put your id's here
var tb = document.getElementById('TEXTBOX_ID');

cb.onchange = function() { // listen for event change
   if(!cb.checked) { // check state
       tb.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
   else {
       tb.style.visibility = 'visible';
   }
}
```